# matlab's odd xtick/ytick label behavior

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I stumbled upon an unintuitive behavior of matlab's xticklabels and yticklabels behavior. I store the output of xticklabels into a variable, modify it, then apply it again and notice the labels are now shifted. Is this expected behavior, if so *why* (optional: why does it make sense to have this as expected behavior)?

Idea: show xticks for every step, but only display label for every second step.

```
%setup a figure to display
figure;
data=randn(1,21);
plot(-10:10,data);
xlim([-5 10]) %cut out a piece of interest from the data
xticks(-10:2:10); %adjust tick spacing to favorite

%now: keep xticks but remove every 2nd label
lbls=xticklabels;
lbls(1:2:end)={' '}; %set every 2nd label to empty space
pause(1); %take a deep breath...
xticklabels(lbls)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as explained in [Gianfranco Di Domenico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67034521/2586922), is caused by Matlab treating the tick labels differently when reading them (`labels = xticklabels`) and when specifying them (`xticklabels(labels)`). But the actual behaviour is a little more interesting...

### Behaviour of tick labels when reading them and when specifying them

These is what I found after some testing. It feels more complicated than it should be (maybe I'm missing something that would make the description simpler?).

1. If the `'XTickLabelMode'` property has the value `'Auto'`, tick labels are **automatically** chosen based on the current ticks.

   **Example**:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:8)
   xlim([2 7])
   xticks, xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives

   ```
   ans =
        2     3     4     5     6     7
   ans =
     1×6 cell array
       {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
   ```

   This tick behaviour is the same even even if the axis ticks are set manually:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:8)
   xticks(3:7)
   xticks, xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives

   ```
   ans =
    3     4     5     6     7
   ans =
     1×5 cell array
       {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
   ```

   Apparently, the behaviour can be affected by the grouping of graphics events to be processed:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:8)
   xlim([2 7])
   drawnow % force axis creation before setting 'XTickLabelMode'
   set(gca, 'XTickLabelMode', 'manual')
   xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives a result consistent with the above:

   ```
   ans =
     1×6 cell array
       {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
   ```

   whereas removing `drawnow` produces a different result:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:8)
   xlim([2 7])
   set(gca, 'XTickLabelMode', 'manual')
   xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives

   ```
   ans =
     0×0 empty char array
   ```

   The likely explanation is that, without `drawnow`, both graphics events (axis creation and setting the property) are processed in one go and that somehow affects the result.
2. If the `'XTickLabelMode'` property has the value `'Manual'`, reading the tick labels returns the labels **as they were set** by the user (more on this in (3) and (4) below), which may not coincide with the labels that are currently seen on the graph. So now the returned result may not match the current axis limits.

   Setting the tick labels manually with `xticklabels(...)` or with `set(gca, 'xticklabels', ...)` **implicitly** causes the `'XTickLabelMode'` property to have the value `'Manual'`. Also, this property may be **explicitly** set to `'Manual'` with `set(gca, 'XTickLabelMode', 'Manual')`.

   **Example**:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:7)
   xticklabels({'a' 'b' 'c'})
   xlim([2 6])
   get(gca, 'XTickLabelMode')
   xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives

   ```
   ans =
       'manual'
   ans =
     1×7 cell array
       {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}
   ```

   and the plot shows these tick labels:

   [image]
3. When **setting the tick labels manually** they are interpreted as **referring to the current axis ticks**, regardless of the current axis limits, and thus regardless of how many of the axis ticks are actually visible.

   **Example**: in the above figure, note how the first label (`'a'`) is not visible. This is because the axis ticks are (by default) `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:7)
   xticklabels({'a' 'b' 'c'})
   xlim([2 6])
   xticks
   ans =
        1     2     3     4     5     6     7
   ```

   The first label refers to the first tick, which is outside of the axis limits set by `xlim`, and thus it is not seen.
4. When setting the tick labels manually **with `xticklabels(...)`**, if the number of provided labels is less than the number of ticks, the missing labels at the end are assumed to be the **empty string**.

   **Example**: in the above figure, note how labels beyond `'c'` are empty.
5. When setting the tick labels manually **with `set(gca, 'xticklabels', ...)`**, if the number of provided labels is less than the number of ticks Matlab **cyclically reuses** them in the displayed graph to match the number of ticks.

   **Example**:

   ```
   clf
   plot(1:7)
   xticks(1:7)
   set(gca, 'xticklabels', {'a' 'b' 'c'})
   xlim([2 6])
   xticklabels.'
   ```

   gives the following (note also that the first label is not seen because of (3)):

   ```
   ans =
     1×3 cell array
       {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}
   ```

   [image]

### Does it make sense for the behaviour to be as described?

I think it does. It may seem complicated at first, but it is consistent.

**Example** (implicit change of tick label mode):

```
>> clf
plot(1:7)
xticks(0:7)
get(gca, 'XTickLabelMode'), xticklabels.'
disp('Pausing...'), pause % press key to continue
labels = xticklabels; % read current tick labels
xticklabels(labels) % this causes 'XLabelMode' to take the value 'Manual'
get(gca, 'XTickLabelMode'), xticklabels.'
```

gives

```
ans =
    'auto'
ans =
  1×7 cell array
    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
Pausing...
ans =
    'manual'
ans =
  1×8 cell array
    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}    {0×0 char}
```

Before the pause, the tick labels are in `'Auto'` mode, so they are automatically chosen based on the ticks that are currently visible.

After the pause, the code reads the axis tick labels, writes back what was just read and reads again; and this gives a **different result** from the reading before the pause. The reason is that the interpretation of the tick labels has been changed from (1) to (2) between the two readings. But there is no ambiguity, because the `'XTickLabelMode'` property of the axis has changed from `'Auto'` to `'Manual'` to reflect that.

In this example, the change of `'XTickLabelMode'` has been implicitly triggered by the user setting the tick labels manually. What if that property is explicitly changed to `'Manual'`? The results are still consistent, as shown next.

**Example** (explicit change of tick label mode):

```
clf
plot(1:7)
xticks(0:7)
get(gca, 'XTickLabelMode'), xticklabels.'
disp('Pausing...'), pause % press key to continue
set(gca, 'XTickLabelMode', 'Manual')
get(gca, 'XTickLabelMode'), xticklabels.'
```

gives

```
ans =
    'auto'
ans =
  1×7 cell array
    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
Pausing...
ans =
    'manual'
ans =
  1×7 cell array
    {'1'}    {'2'}    {'3'}    {'4'}    {'5'}    {'6'}    {'7'}
```

The plot right before the pause has the tick labels in `'Auto'` mode, and they work as expected.

The plot after the pause has the tick labels in `'Manual'` mode. The tick labels are the same as before, but in this mode they apply to all ticks, even those outside the axis limits. So there is one tick label fewer than needed, and Matlab reuses the first label for the last tick according to (5) above:

- Before:

  [image]
- After:

  [image]

So inspecting the `'XTickLabelMode'` property is a **valid** way to determine whether the read tick labels should be interpreted according to (1) or to (2).

Comment: To me the obvious conclusion is to always set both the ticks and the tick labels at the same time. Very weird behavior, this. I wonder if this is a HG2 thing? I don’t remember ever running into this back in the old days.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Same here. I was expecting something cleaner

Comment: this answer encompasses a mini-phd... this hole of inconsistency is probably deeper than anyone suspected. Thanks for the work, IMHO it should be a blog post in undocumented matlab, or just directly reported as a bug. For reference: I was using MATLAB ver 2020B.

Comment: @user2305193 Thank you! The issue was intriguing, and I did spend a good part of today doing the testing. Yes, it looks like a bug

Comment: @LuisMendo it would be great if you were the person to report (that is, if you would want to, anyway!), since I think after this answer you could probably give some explicit suggestions on how to improve the behavior (and possibly minimizing compatibility issues). Otherwise, I'll do this at some point but would really only point to your research in any case.

Comment: @user2305193 I just sent the description to an engineer I know in Mathworks, who perhaps can get an explanation from the developers. I think that may be better than a bug report, because it’s not totally clear whether this is a bug or just a quirk

Comment: @user2305193 I got some feedback from Mathworks. Based on their explanation I realized that the inconsistency I was seeing was not actually there (I just made a bad choice of values in the example, which misled me). I have edited the answer. Hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that, while `xtick` function returns the value of all the existing ticks (visible and hidden ones), the  `xticklabels` function only returns the labels of visible ticks. I guess this behavior is due to the fact that MATLAB does not assign any label to non-visible ticks.
Therefore, your xtick vector is:

```
[-10 -8 -6 -4 -2 0 2 4 6 8 10]
```

While your xticklabels cell array is:

```
{'-4'}, {'-2'}, {'0'}, {'2'}, {'4'}, {'6'}, {'8'}, {'10'}
```

and, after replacing:

```
{' '}, {'-2'}, {' '}, {'2'}, {' '}, {'6'}, {' '}, {'10'}
```

As the only visible ticks in your picture are the ones assigned to the ones ranging from -4 to 10, the corresponding shown labels are the elements in the cell array from the fourth to the last. The ticks that do not get a label assigned (because there are less labels than ticks) are characterized by an empty cell:

```
{'2'}, {' '}, {'6'}, {' '}, {'10'}, {empty}, {empty}, {empty}
```

**Solution:**
You have multiple solution. The first one is to delete the ticks that do not fall inside the x-axis limits:

```
%setup a figure to display
figure;
data=randn(1,21);
plot(-10:10,data);
xlim([-5 10]) %cut out a piece of interest from the data
xticks(-10:2:10);  %adjust tick spacing to favorite

% Delete external ticks
xt = xticks();
xl = xlim(); xt(xt<xl(1)) = []; xt(xt>xl(2)) = []; xticks(xt);

%now: keep xticks but remove every 2nd label
lbls=xticklabels;
lbls(1:2:end)={' '}; %set every 2nd label to empty space
pause(1); %take a deep breath...
xticklabels(lbls)
```

[Result(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqWHp.png)

The other solution is to assign the labels manually converting the numbers returned by xticks to string values:

```
%setup a figure to display
figure;
data=randn(1,21);
plot(-10:10,data);
xlim([-5 10]) %cut out a piece of interest from the data
xticks(-10:2:10);  %adjust tick spacing to favorite

%now: keep xticks but remove every 2nd label
lbls= arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x), xticks(), 'UniformOutput', false);
lbls(1:2:end)={' '}; %set every 2nd label to empty space
pause(1); %take a deep breath...
xticklabels(lbls)
```

[Result(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zENFJ.png)

You will notice that the ticks are different between the two solutions. It is due to the fact that the even/odd elements are different between the two vectors and therefore, different elements are replaced with the whitespace.

Comment: right! Any idea as to why xticklabels would return only the displayed xticks, but when setting, it assumes you want to specify all visible *and* invisible ticks?

Comment: Nice answer! However, it is not always true that _the `xticklabel` function only returns the labels of visible ticks_. It seems to be a little more complicated; see my answer